# Allocate dynamic array with interdependent dimensions

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is a bit complicated; I'd welcome any comments on how to improve the clarity of the question.

Ok, say I have an array:

```
real, allocatable :: A(:,:,:)
```

and I want to allocate it before I use it. Is it possible for the size of third dimension to depend on the size of the second dimension?

E.g.

```
do i=1,n
allocate(A(3,i,i**2))
end do
```

Obviously the above doesn't work. I'd like to end up with an array (or a set of arrays) with the shape(s)

```
(3,1,1), (3,2,4), (3,3,9), ... (3, n, n^2)
```

where the size of the third dimension is the square of the size of the second dimension.

My rule for the size of the dependent dimension is a bit more complicated, but if squaring is possible I can do the rest.

Is this possible? If so, how might I implement it in Fortran?

What would `shape(A)` return? That would be interesting.

My other alternative is to allocate to the maximum size required, and be careful to only use certain elements in calculations, i.e.

```
allocate(A(3,n,n**2))
```

Even though I'm not hard up on memory at the moment, I'd like to have good programming practices. This is an interesting problem anyway.

Thank you.

EDIT:

What about having the size of a dimension depend on the *value* of an element in another dimension?

In the answer below the size of array in both dimensions depended on the index of B. I'd like something along the lines of

```
type myarray
    real :: coord(3)
    integer,allocatable :: lev(:)
    integer, allocatable :: cell(:)
endtype myarray

type(myarray), allocatable :: data

allocate(data(m))
allocate(data%lev(n))

forall (j=1:n) !simple now, for argument's sake
    lev(j)=j
endforall

! I was thinking of using a FORALL loop here, but the errors returned 
! suggested that the compiler (gfortran) didn't expect IF blocks and ALLOCATE 
! statements in a FORALL block
do i=1,m
    do j=1,n
        allocate(data(i)%cell(lev(j)**2))
    enddo
enddo
```

You get what I mean? But the program falls over as it tries to allocate already allocated variables, e.g. when `i=1` it allocates `data(1)%cell(1)`, and then tries to allocate `data(1)%cell(2)`...uh oh. What I want is something like:

Each `data(i)` has an array `lev(j)` of values, with `j` running from 1 to n, and for each `lev(j)` value we have a `cell` of size `lev`^2. Note that these `cell`'s are unique for each `data(i)` and each `lev`, and that the size of that particular `cell` depends on the corresponding `lev` value, and possibly the corresponding `data(i)` too.

Would I have to use a derived type within a derived type?

Comment: Just so you know, the type of array you're looking for is called a "jagged" array, as vs. "rectangular" array.  IRO-bot below has the correct answer; in Fortran arrays by themselves are always rectangular but you can use defined types to make your own structure.

Comment: "Jagged"...hey, that makes sense, pictorially. "...you can use defined types to make your own structure." Really? So if I want an array whose shape increases until halfway then decreases, or follows the Fibonacci sequence, or is completely random--that's all possible for not too much effort...cool!

Comment: @SamuelTan I further edited my answer with updated code to solve your new problem. Compare the two codes to see what you were doing wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use a derived type to accomplish this:

```
TYPE array
  REAL,DIMENSION(:,:,:),ALLOCATABLE :: A
ENDTYPE array

INTEGER :: i
INTEGER,PARAMETER :: n=10

TYPE(array),DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: B

ALLOCATE(B(n))

DO i=1,n
  ALLOCATE(B(i)%A(3,i,i*i))
  WRITE(*,*)SHAPE(B(i)%A)
ENDDO

END
```

This approach allows each element of array B to be a multi-dimensional array of a different shape.

The output of the program is as expected:

```
        3            1            1
        3            2            4
        3            3            9
        3            4           16
        3            5           25
        3            6           36
        3            7           49
        3            8           64
        3            9           81
        3           10          100
```

EDIT: To further answer OP's edited question. Yes, it seems like you would need to do something like this, use nested derived type (compare to your code example to figure out what you did wrong):

```
integer,parameter :: m=3,n=5

type cellarray
  integer,dimension(:),allocatable :: c
endtype cellarray

type myarray
  integer,allocatable :: lev(:)
  type(cellarray),dimension(:),allocatable :: cell
endtype myarray

type(myarray),dimension(:),allocatable :: B

allocate(B(m))

! Allocate and assign lev and cell:
do i=1,m
  allocate(B(i)%lev(n))
  allocate(B(i)%cell(n))
  do j=1,n
    B(i)%lev(j)=j
  enddo
enddo

! Based on value of lev, allocate B%cell%c:    
do i=1,m
  do j=1,n
    allocate(B(i)%cell(j)%c(B(i)%lev(j)**2))
  enddo
enddo

! Print out to check that it works:
do j=1,n
  write(*,*)j,B(1)%lev(j),SIZE(B(1)%cell(j)%c)
enddo

end
```

Tried this with gfortran 4.6.2. It produces expected output:

```
       1           1           1
       2           2           4
       3           3           9
       4           4          16
       5           5          25
```

Comment: It works with any recent gfortran I have encountered (4.1.2 is totally obsolete).

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the comment - I editted my answer. I was not aware of this since I barely ever use gfortran, and this is what we have on our compute cluster. I assume our sysadmin didn't bother updating it. :)

Comment: That's a consolation. I use gfortran, and I was afraid I might have to get another compiler.

Comment: What happens if we have `B` allocatable as well? Would the allocation still take one loop?

Comment: @SamuelTan No, you would allocate B in a single statement, just like you would any other array. Remember that you allocate elements of B inside the loop because each is different shape. I edited my answer so that B is allocatable.

Comment: Yes!!! Awesome! Thank you so much! It works! Derived type of a derived type! Erm...does this make things run slower? You know, type within type, and a few nested loops? I will be looping through this array later on as well. I'm doing this with atoms, which have xyz coordinates (`coord`), a level (`lev`), and a unit cell they belong to (`cell`). They have other attributes like charge and elemental symbol. Is it a good idea to have all their attributes in a single derived type, or is it more optimal to have these properties separate if possible?

Comment: @SamuelTan I have no experience with derived types in HPC - you will have to figure out this yourself. I assume it should not be significantly slower, remember that derived types are just an abstraction of data, and it is all stored in 1-D arrays in memory. As an exercise, you can implement your problem both ways, and see if you get difference in performance. However, what I would worry about is to first implement the program in the simplest and most obvious way that works for you, and worry about optimizing later.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this simply by allocating/deallocating the array

```
Program test
    Implicit none
    Real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: A
    Integer  :: i,N
    Write(*,*)"Enter N"; Read(*,*)N
    Do i = 1, N
    if(Allocated(A)) then 
    deallocate(A);Allocate(A(i,i,i*i))
    else
    allocate(A(i,i,i*i))
    end if
    Write(*,*)Shape(A)
    End do
end program test
```

Compiling the program using gfortran gives:

```
 Enter N
5
           1           1           1
           2           2           4
           3           3           9
           4           4          16
           5           5          25
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think you may have missed the point of the question.  The question seems to be asking about non-rectangular/jagged arrays, and the asker already mentions the idea about having the largest super-rectangle and using (with care) only those desired elements.

Comment: *Is it possible for the size of third dimension to depend on the size of the second dimension?*  So yes or no? I can't see the answer to this in your answer.

Comment: I agree that this is indeed an answer to the literal question.  However, given the comments on the question and the accepted answer (and interpreting the question a little differently) I'd read what is wanted more as: "can I have an array which has `A(:,1,:)` as shape (3,1), `A(:,2,:)` as shape (3,4), ..., `A(:,n,:)` (3,n^2).

Comment: Well, I agree with francescalus, we both interpreted the question differently than you (and I strongly believe closer to the OP's intention).  He (because he accepted the above answer) was actually asking *Is it possible for the size of third dimension to be different for different indexes of the second dimension?*